# How to dynamically create and populate a new Matrix within a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a Python nested for loop that processes a list of strings, appends and applies np.asarray the final result is below. However the next time round the loop a counter (`j`) changes and has new data.

```
for j in some range
      selectedData[j].myDataSource
      for thisData in selectedData[j].myDataSource
          # do stuff
          newArray.append(my1darray)
      targetArray = np.asarray(newArray)
```

How can I get it to write to another array (since affixing `[j]` to the array name (`targetArray`) won't work).

```
[['LOCAL' 'boy' '140.00112000' ..., ':' '2017-12-21' '02:02:14|']
 ['NOTLOCAL' 'boy' '47.04037632' ..., ':' '2017-12-21' '02:00:12|']
 ['NOTLOCAL' 'girl' '87.99201250' ..., ':' '2017-12-21' '01:52:54|']
 ..., 
 ['LOCAL' 'girl' '14.80000000' ..., ':' '2017-12-14' '08:27:20|']
 ['NOTLOCAL' 'girl' '3.45676910' ..., ':' '2017-12-14' '08:03:42|']
 ['NOTLOCAL' 'boy' '3.40756921' ..., ':' '2017-12-14' '05:22:53|']]
```

Number of elements in the row, remain constant, number of rows depend on data  being called.

Comment: if you must iterate collect values in a list (of lists) and create the array once at the end,  But if you want a mix of strings and numbers you need to make a structured array.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make `targetArray` a list of numpy matricies and append to it?

```
targetArrays = []
for j in some range
    selectedData[j].myDataSource
    for thisData in selectedData[j].myDataSource
        # do stuff
        newArray.append(my1darray)
    targetArray.append(np.asarray(newArray))
```

Comment: ^^ THAT WORKED! One and a half days I have been looking or the answer, thanks so much! FYI I had to add newArray = [] just before the for loop as it was in another for loop and needs to be initialized each time.